# how do I check the pressed down key using TSDL in OCAML?

Tags: ocaml, sdl

This is the piece of code I want to write in OCAML taken from a C++ tutorial :

```c
// Set texture based on current keystate
 const Uint8* currentKeyStates = SDL_GetKeyboardState( NULL );
 if ( currentKeyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_UP ] ) {
    currentTexture = &gUpTexture;
} else if( currentKeyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN ] ) {
    currentTexture = &gDownTexture;
} else if( currentKeyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT ] ) {
    currentTexture = &gLeftTexture;
} else if( currentKeyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT ] ) {
    currentTexture = &gRightTexture;
} else {
    currentTexture = &gPressTexture;
}
```

This C code uses the SDL library. In OCAML, I use the TSDL library which is thin bindings to the SDL library.

Here's the signature for SDL_GetKeyBoardState

```ml
val get_keyboard_state : unit -> (int, Bigarray.int8_unsigned_elt) bigarray
```

I am not quite sure how to do

```
currentKeyStates[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]
```

in OCAML.

Please help? Thank you!

This is what I've tried so far :

```
let key_state = Sdl.get_keyboard_state () in
key_state.(Sdl.Scancode.up)
```

The error states that `.()` cannot be applied to bigarrays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.{}` for indexing Bigarrays:

```
key_state.{Sdl.Scancode.up}
```

Comment: thank you. it messes vs code's ocaml package syntax coloring tho, do you know why?

Comment: nvm, i fixed it by adding parentheses around